# How would I make an array to store strings?

Tags: c

So I'm trying to figure this out with a simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
 int main()
{
    char a[]="lalala";
    char b[]="bababa";
    char c[]="nanana";
    char d[3][10];

    d[0][20]=*a;
    d[1][20]=*b;
    d[2][20]=*c;
    printf("%s -- %s -- %s", d[0], d[1], d[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I run it, this is what comes out:

```
( -- ╡■   :A&w═l&wÉ∟@ -- l&wÉ∟@
```

What I'm trying to do is make it print out
lalala
bababa
nanana

Am I missing something obvious or do I need to do something more complicated to make an array for strings?

Comment: What language is this, C? Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using strcpy instead of assigning them by dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

To store entire string use string copy.

```
char a[]="lalala"; 
char c[]="nanana";
char d[3][10];

strcpy(d[0],a);
strcpy(d[1],b);
strcpy(d[2],c);

printf("%s -- %s -- %s", d[0], d[1], d[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The declaration `char a[] = "lalala";` creates an array of characters, where the name `a` is an alias for the memory address where the first character is stored.

To create an array of strings, you can make an array of character *pointers*, each of which holds the memory address of the starting position of a single character array.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    /* Store the starting address of each character array in an array of
     * character pointers */

    char alpha[] = "Alpha";  /* Array of characters */
    char beta[] = "Beta";
    char gamma[] = "Gamma";

    char *char_ptr_array[3]; /* Array of pointers to characters */

    char_ptr_array[0] = &alpha[0]; 
    char_ptr_array[1] = beta; 
        /* This does the same thing since the array's name is an alias
         * for the address of the first element */
    char_ptr_array[2] = gamma;

    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", char_ptr_array[0], char_ptr_array[1], char_ptr_array[2]);

    return(0);
}
```

You can also make the assignment like this, which is a shorthand for doing the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *alphabet[3] = { "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma" };

    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", alphabet[0], alphabet[1], alphabet[2]);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array of strings:

```
std::string test[20];
```

And avoid using `#include <string.h>`; use just `#include <string>`.

Comment: Since you posted this answer the question has been tagged as C, not C++.